# How to display the category featured images

Tags: categories, theme-development, hooks, post-thumbnails

I have a custom theme that for the latest posts displays the posts thumbnail. What I am looking to do is to check and if there is no thumbnail set then use the category's featured image. I could upload the images and use this:

```
if (!$photo) :
        $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
        $photo = '<div class="related-content-box__photo" style="background-image: url(' . $uploads['baseurl'] . '/2017/01/' . $category_name . '.jpg' . ')"></div>';
    endif;
```

What I don't like about this is that if I want to change one image of a category I have to upload all of them again and change the year/month of the folder.

So I have uploaded the images as featured images for the category themselves but how can I display them?

Comment: I suggests to use a plugin that adds featured images to taxonomies, including categories, so you can set a relationship between a category and an image and you can work with that relationship programmatically withing your theme. For example [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/categories-images/). Otherwise, I'm not sure what are you asking for.

Comment: How did you upload the images as featured category images? This is not a feature vanilla WordPress would have.

Comment: I used the ACF custom field to upload a featured image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found so far was to add featured image for categories as a custom field using ACF and then using the category ID to find and display each featured image.

Hope it helps anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is any good it uses `get_the_post_thumbnail` to retrieve the featured image. This function has a filter that you can use to detect whether there is a featured images and if not replace it. Like this:

```
add_filter ('post_thumbnail_html','wpse251260_thumbnail_html', 10, 5)

wpse251260_thumbnail_html ($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
  if ( '' === $html ) {
    .. do stuff depending on category you retrieve with $post_id;
    }
   return $html
  }
```

Comment: Just in case: you can use [add_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/) to add a metabox to the category to set a featured image per category.